# python check if a String is palindrome or not in an array

Tags: python, arrays, string, palindrome

For example I have this array:

`array = ['b2', 'jy', 'n3', 'ih', 'fc']`

And I am trying to access each index of the array to check if is palindrome or not.

```
for i in range(len(array[i])):

    if array[i] == array[len(pal)-i-1]:
        booleano = "true"

    else:
        booleano = "false"


if booleano != "true":
    return false

else: return true
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the code you show? Read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs)

Comment: This can also be useful to verify conditions in a list: http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk

Answer (score 3):

You can check if `string` is *palindrome* using `[::-1]` slicing.

```
lst = ['bb', 'jhj', 'n3', 'ih', 'fc']
palindromes = [item == item[::-1] for item in lst]
```

Output

```
[True, True, False, False, False]
```

Comment: `[item == item[::-1]] for item in lst]` might be closer to what they asked for, also maybe debug their *current* code too

Comment: Instead of that kind of output how can I have like:

`lst = ['bb true', 'jhj true', 'n3 false', 'ih false', 'fc false']`

Comment: @AfonsoPinto, something like this: `palindromes = [item + ' '+ str(item == item[::-1])  for item in lst]`